# VueJS cargar datos desde computed a tabla ag grid vue, con Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables, vuex

estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de una plantilla propia y utilizo en ella vuex, tengo integrado Ag Grid-Vue para cargar y lista la data pero, llegue a una parte donde no se bien como cargar la data a mi tabla, recibo efectivamente la data desde el store, cargada en computed, como muestro en la imagen de abajo, mi duda es como puedo hacer para pasar esa data a mi arreglo y se cargue en la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo completo, incluido mi template para ver las propiedades de la libreria:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div class="text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-success mb-1" @click.prevent="crearcustomer">Crear registro</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ag-grid-vue style="width: 100%; height: 770px;" class="ag-theme-material w-100 my-1 ag-grid-table bg-white rounded shadow-lg"
      ref="agGridTable"
      :columnDefs="columnDefs"
      :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
      :rowData="usersData"
      :gridOptions="gridOptions"
      rowSelection="multiple"
      colResizeDefault="shift"
      :animateRows="true"
      :floatingFilter="true"
      :pagination="true"
      >
    </ag-grid-vue>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue";
import CellRendererActions from "../customers/CellRendererActions.vue";

export default {
  name: 'CustomerList',
     components: {
       /* eslint-disable vue/no-unused-components */
      AgGridVue,
      CellRendererActions
    },
    data() {
        return {
        id: '',
        nombre: '',
        rut: '',
        direccion:'',
        email: '',
        giro: '',
        // AgGrid
        gridApi: null,
        gridOptions: {},
        defaultColDef: {
          sortable: true,
          resizable: true,
          suppressMenu: true
        },
        columnDefs: [
          {headerName: 'ID', field: 'id', filter: true, width: 350, sortable: true,  checkboxSelection: true, headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true, headerCheckboxSelection: true},
          {headerName: 'Nombre', field: 'nombre', filter: true, width: 300, sortable: true, },
          {headerName: 'Dirección', field: 'direccion', filter: true, width: 300, sortable: true, },
          {headerName: 'Rut', field: 'rut', filter: true, width: 100, sortable: true, },
          {headerName: 'Correo', field: 'email', filter: true, width: 200, sortable: true, },
          {headerName: 'Giro', field: 'giro', filter: true, width: 150, sortable: true, },
          {headerName: 'Acciones',  width: 150, cellRendererFramework: 'CellRendererActions'},
        ],
        usersData: [
          {  id: 'id',  nombre: 'nombre',  direccion: 'direccion',  rut: 'rut',  email: 'email',  giro: 'giro'  },
        ],
        //Cell render de botones
        components: {
          CellRendererActions,
      }, 
    }
  },
  computed: {
      getcustomers(){
        return this.$store.getters.sendingcustomers.filter(datos =>{
            return datos.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(this.nombre.toLowerCase())
        })
    } 
  },
    created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('traerclientes');
    },
    
    methods: {
      crearcustomer(){
        this.$router.push('/customers/create')
      }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  
</style>
```

ya hice pruebas con un api pero traer desde una base de datos en firebase me complica el como cargar la data a la tabla.

este es mi codigo en el store.js

```
state: {
    uidUser: '',
    customers: [],
  },
  getters: {
    sendingcustomers(state){
      return state.customers;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    traeclientes(state) {
      db.collection("clientes").doc("cliente").collection("registro").onSnapshot(datos=> {
        let auxiliar = [];
        datos.forEach(elementos=>{
          auxiliar.push({
            idDoc: elementos.id,
            id: elementos.data().id,
            nombre: elementos.data().nombre,
            rut: elementos.data().rut,
            direccion: elementos.data().direccion,
            email: elementos.data().email,
            giro: elementos.data().giro
          })
        })
        state.customers = auxiliar
      })
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto el problema aplicando el clico mounted como muestro en el codigo abajo...

```
mounted() {
    this.usersData = this.getcustomers
  },
```

Dejo post por si le sirve a alguien para solucionar el problema...